# How can I use filterFunction in ColumnSeries

Tags: apache-flex, flex-charting, flex-charts

I have a set of data like the following:

```
        [Bindable]
    public var Loc:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
        {date:"2002", close:41.87, loc: "Location 01"},
        {date:"2003", close:45.74, loc: "Location 01"},
        {date:"2004", close:42.77, loc: "Location 01"},
        {date:"2005", close:48.06, loc: "Location 01"},
        {date:"2006", close:48.06, loc: "Location 01"},
        {date:"2002", close:157.59, loc: "Location 02"},
        {date:"2003", close:160.3, loc: "Location 02"},
        {date:"2004", close:150.71, loc: "Location 02"},
        {date:"2005", close:156.88, loc: "Location 02"},
    ]);
```

and I'd like to create a chart like the following, in which each location is displayed in different color and grouped by each year:
[image]

I was thinking that I must use "mx:ColumnSeries" tag and use its "filterFunction" property to define how to filter the data for each location as a separate series, but I don't know how to do that. Does anyboy have any recommendation or sample code for creating such charts?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here an example:

```
private function filterSeries1(cache:Array):Array
{
    var filteredCache:Array = [];
    for (var i:int = 0; i < cache.length; i++)
    {
        var item:ColumnSeriesItem = ColumnSeriesItem(cache[i]);
        if(item.item.loc == "Location 01")
            filteredCache.push(item);
    }
    return filteredCache;
}

private function filterSeries2(cache:Array):Array
{
    var filteredCache:Array = [];
    for (var i:int = 0; i < cache.length; i++)
    {
        var item:ColumnSeriesItem = ColumnSeriesItem(cache[i]);
        if(item.item.loc == "Location 02")
            filteredCache.push(item);
    }
    return filteredCache;
}
```

And:

```
<mx:series>
    <mx:ColumnSeries yField="close" xField="date"
                     labelPosition="outside"
                     filterFunction="{filterSeries1}"/>
    <mx:ColumnSeries yField="close" xField="date"
                     labelPosition="outside"
                     filterFunction="{filterSeries2}"/>
</mx:series>
```